# How to prevent Screen lock ios with Qt

Tags: ios, qt, screen, qml, screen-lock

I want to develop an app in Qt for iOS that contains a map. During the use, the screen lock of the phone should be disabled. 
But I can't find any solution how to prevent the screen lock in iOS using Qt.

How can be done that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use the native iOS api. You can compile ObjC++ code directly with the clang compiler in your Qt application.

So you can mix `.cpp` and `.mm` (ObjC++) files. QtCreator and `qmake` support this via the `OBJECTIVE_SOURCES` keyword.

In a `yourclass.mm` implementation:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    void YourClass::setTimerDisabled() {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES] 
    }
```

`yourclass.h`:

```
class YourClass
{
public:
   void setTimerDisabled()
}
```

Now you can call from anywhere in your Qt-app:

```
YourClass yc;
yc.setTimerDisbabled();
```

In your project file (`.pro`), if you only want this file on iOS:

```
ios {
OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += \
    yourclass.mm \
}
```

And if you only want specified code on a single platform, use preprocessor commands in your source and header files like this:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_IOS)
   // iOs stuff
#elsif defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
   //Android stuff ...
#else
  //Other stuff ...
#endif
```

Comment: thanks Hubi! But now I have the problem that qt can't find Foundation if i compile it for Android. 
My app should work on both operating systems. Can you give me a further hint?

Comment: Now I can compile everything and the App runs on the IOS, but unfortunately the display doesn't keep awake. And in the Qt Creator the [[UIApplication ... line is displayed as unknown. Can you help me one more time? :)

Comment: OK, now it works! I just had to add the line "LIBS += -framework UIKit into the ios { } part of the .pro file. 

Thank you very much, Hubi!

Comment: This worked great!  My app updates firmware on a Bluetooth connected device.  Updates take 10 minutes and would fail due to iOS auto-lock.  While the iOS Settings > Display > Auto-Lock > Never, would prevent the problems, this solution is much better.  Thank you!